# Is there a good Open Source, XSD based Web Editor?

Tags: xml, open-source, webforms, xsd

I'm looking for a good open source web editor that will take xsd (or some other standard XML) and from that generate web forms that will enable the end user to generate standard xml (without knowing anything about xml obliviously). I took a look at kupu, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation and the site appears to no longer exist. Is there anything out there that does this already.

I could write something like this myself, but if there's something that out there that will save me some time that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: might be same requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424708/what-is-the-best-free-editor-for-xslt-and-mybe-xslfo-and-xml/2425297#2425297

Comment: I'm not really looking for an IDE, but rather something that will dynamically build webforms based on xml or an xsd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK [Xopus](http://xopus.com) is the only XSD based Web Editor currently supported. It is not open source, but is especially designed for the end users you're targeting.

It takes XML, XSD and XSL to create a friendly and 100% validating WYSIWYG editing UI. Take a look at the [demos](http://xopus.com/demos.html) to see what is possible.

Disclaimer: I work at Xopus.

Comment: Can you explain where the XSD files are in the demos? I couldn't find links to any of them.

Comment: Ok, I found them. You have to download the files for the Demo to see it, e.g., http://xopus.com/files/demo/recipe.zip